# How to display streambuilder and dropdown correctly in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm a new flutter developer and a bit confused here, I want to display a dropdown menu and the streambuilder in my screen. Here's the code for the dropdown.

```
      DropdownButton<String>(
        value: selectedItem,
        items: services,
        .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value:item,
          child: Text(item, style: TextStyle(fonSize: 24))
        )).toList(),
        onChanged: (item) => setState(() => selectedItem - item),
      )
```

Here's the scaffold with streambuilder

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      
      body: StreamBuilder<List<SportBooking>>(
          stream: readBooking(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Something went wrong! ${snapshot.error}');
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final booking = snapshot.data!;
              return ListView(
                children: booking.map(buildBooking).toList(),
              );
            } else {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          }),
    );
  }
```

Problem is I have tried with a Column widget here like below with a simple text widget, but it throws an Assertion error

```
body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('data'),
          StreamBuilder<List<SportBooking>>(
              stream: readBooking(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Something went wrong! ${snapshot.error}');
                } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final booking = snapshot.data!;
                  return ListView(
                    children: booking.map(buildBooking).toList(),
                  );
                } else {
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              }),
        ],
      ),
```

How do I display both the dropdown and the streambuilder in the scaffold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ListView add the following properties

```
ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    shrinkWrap: true,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it inside a `Column` Widget and now you can add as many Widgets as you want.

You can either wrap `ListView` with `Column` Widget.

Make sure to Wrap `ListView` with `Expanded` Widget otherwise it will give exception.

```dart
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          DropdownButton<String>(
        value: selectedItem,
        items: services,
        .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value:item,
          child: Text(item, style: TextStyle(fonSize: 24))
        )).toList(),
        onChanged: (item) => setState(() => selectedItem - item),
      ),
          StreamBuilder<List<SportBooking>>(
              stream: readBooking(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Something went wrong! ${snapshot.error}');
                } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final booking = snapshot.data!;
                  return ListView(
                    children: booking.map(buildBooking).toList(),
                  );
                } else {
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Weirdly I tried this before but didn't work

Comment: Please provide the code you tried. This is the only way AFAIK.

Comment: I made it simple by just adding Text Widget. It throws an error something about assertion @Usama

Comment: You can check the question again I added the example.

Comment: Needed scrolldirection property and shrinkwrap on my ListView. Works now.